Showing and Hide a div with JS/jQuery in a Wordpress loop
I am looking for some help using JS or jQuery to show and hide a div. I have social media share in Wordpress loop. I understand how to make show and hide div on click. But in Wordpress loop, when I click share button all divs appear.


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('.loop-item .share-btn').click(function(){
      $('.loop-item .share-icon').toggle();   
  });
  
});
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.loop-container {
  display: flex;
}

.loop-item {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.loop-item h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.social-share-box {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.social-share-box .share-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.social-share-box .share-icon {
  display: none;
}

.social-share-box .share-icon.active {
  display: block;
}

.social-share-box .share-icon a {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="loop-container">

  <div class="loop-item">
    <h4>Item Title Loop 1</h4>
    <div class="social-share-box">
      <div class="share-btn">
          Click here share:
      </div>
      <div class="share-icon">
        <a>F</a>
        <a>T</a>
        <a>P</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="loop-item">
    <h4>Item Title Loop 2</h4>
        <div class="social-share-box">
      <div class="share-btn">
          Click here share:
      </div>
      <div class="share-icon">
        <a>F</a>
        <a>T</a>
        <a>P</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



As in my code, if I click "Click here share:" the social icon will appear in all posts.
My questions:

How can I make the social icon only appear on the post I clicked?
How to hide the active social media icon when I click on another "Click here share:"?
How to hide the active social media icon if I click outside?


Currently, whenever you press a button, you event handler toggles every .share-icon div.
What you want to do is toggle only the one that is a sibling of the clicked button. Also, you want to hide all the other ones.
To do so, use $(this) to refer to the clicked button
(NB : answers to the thers questions are also in the following code)


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.loop-item .share-btn').click(function() {
    let clicked_btn = $(this);
    
    //toggle the wanted share-icon
    clicked_btn.siblings(".share-icon").toggle();
    
        //hide all other .share-icon
    clicked_btn.siblings(".share-icon").addClass("active");
    $(".loop-item .share-icon:not(.active)").hide()
        $(".loop-item .share-icon.active").removeClass("active");
    
  });

  //hide all share-icon when you click outside of a share-icon
  $("body").click(function(event) {
    if (!event.target.closest(".share-icon,.share-btn")) {
      $(".loop-item .share-icon").hide();
    }
  })
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



event.target.closest(selector) gets the closest element targeted by your click that matches your selector

Check if the current icons are :visible


$(document).on('click', '.loop-item .share-btn', function () {
  const icons = $(this).closest('.loop-item').find('.share-icon');
  if (icons.is(':visible')) {
    $('.loop-item .share-icon').hide();
    return;
  }
  $('.loop-item .share-icon').hide();
  icons.show();
});

$(document).on('click', function (event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest('.share-icon a, .share-btn').length) {
    return;
  }
  $('.loop-item .share-icon').hide();
});
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.loop-container {
  display: flex;
}

.loop-item {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.loop-item h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.social-share-box {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.social-share-box .share-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  user-select:none;
}

.social-share-box .share-icon {
  display: none;
}

.social-share-box .share-icon.active {
  display: block;
}

.social-share-box .share-icon a {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="loop-container">

  <div class="loop-item">
    <h4>Item Title Loop 1</h4>
    <div class="social-share-box">
      <div class="share-btn">
          Click here share:
      </div>
      <div class="share-icon">
        <a>F</a>
        <a>T</a>
        <a>P</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="loop-item">
    <h4>Item Title Loop 2</h4>
        <div class="social-share-box">
      <div class="share-btn">
          Click here share:
      </div>
      <div class="share-icon">
        <a>F</a>
        <a>T</a>
        <a>P</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Hi, thanks for your code. I have tried it, but on the share icon I have to double click to share to social media.
